# Does the transit at Budapest on a train from Belgrade to Zagreb count as staying in the Schengen area?

Tags: public-transport, night-transport, belgrade, zagreb

I read that [you can take a night train from Belgrade to Zagreb](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g294472-i6206-k10220339-Belgrade_to_zagreb-Belgrade.html) (and I  confirmed it in the DB website), but it first goes to Budapest, transfers, and then goes to Zagreb. I also know there's a direct train but I rather want to take the night train in order to save on the accommodation cost.

In this case, is the transit in Budapest handled as a one-day stay in the Schengen area? Or is it like a flight and there's no need to get through immigration?

Comment: Look that the itinerary of those trains, and notice how many stops they make along the way -- it should be fairly clear that the second option couldn't possibly work (especially given what's happening around Europe lately). | Looking at those options, the night train doesn't seem like a very big win, if at all -- twice the time, longer distance (maybe you have rail pass), super early arrival in Budapest, rather cheap hotels in Belgrade, and so on. Might wanna list pros/cons and reevaluate that idea. Will you really save anything for all that extra hassle?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, this counts as entering the Schengen area.  If you will be in Hungary at midnight, it will even count as two days.

With trains, you're generally processed into and out of each country when you actually cross the border.  There are some exceptions, but the trains you are contemplating are not among them.

Comment: "There are some excwptions" They can be counted with just one hand

Comment: Thanks! Could you show me an example of the exception?

Comment: For example with the Eurostar, if you depart from Brussels you pass Belgian exit immigration and UK entry immigration even though you will pass through France on your way (But since both France and Belgium are Schengen, you wouldn’t notice it anyway). And I *think* there were/are also some trains that go from Russia to the Kaliningrad exclave without stopping in the EU which are not considered entering this area.

Comment: @Blaszard yes, I was thinking of the Eurostar.  I don't remember for sure, but I think at least some trains between Canada and the US have preclearance, too.  I'm certainly not aware of a case where such preclearance allows one to change trains without clearing immigration in the way one can in an airport.

Comment: @Coke I was thinking of exceptions to the rule that immigration controls occur before boarding rather than at the border, not exceptions that allow "sterile" transit.  I suspect that there are more than just a handful of the former, though I'm not aware of more than a couple.  I'm not aware of *any* of the latter.  If they exist, perhaps you should expand your answer or post a separate question.

Comment: Slavutych to Chornobyl commuter train, nonstop cuts through Belarus.  I don't believe Belarus customs stops the train.

Comment: @Harper There are tons of similar stuff, but it something different, not relevant here. Train from Liberec to Zittau crosses Poland (but does not stop),  Train from Ebersbach to Wilthen crosses Czechia (but does not stop). These passengers are not considered to enter the country that is just being crossed. These are examples of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privileged_transit_traffic

Comment: @Jan You're wrong about the Kaliningrad Train. It passes through Schengen juridically and Russians Need a Facilitated Rail Transit document issued by the Lithuanian embassy/consulate

Answer (score 8):

The concept of transiting a country's soil without entering the country only exists at airports, with only a couple of provisions for such transit by land transport in the world.

So yes, you'll obviously enter the Schengen Area, with border control taking place at the border.